# React not re-rendering after a change in state, how do I setState of child components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Problem:

I have a collection of Legislators put into a table, the field headers are buttons and have click events attached to them that sort the collection by the field button clicked.

```
render() {
    const legislatorList = this.populateList() //  creates an Array of Legislator components
    return (
      <div className="legislators">
        <h2>Legislators</h2>
        <table className="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><button type="button" onClick={ () => this.handleChange("first_name")}  >First</button></th>
            <th><button type="button" onClick={ () => this.handleChange("last_name")}  >Last</button></th>
            <th><button type="button" onClick={ () => this.handleChange("state")}  >State</button></th>
            <th><button type="button" onClick={ () => this.handleChange("party")}  >Party</button></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
          <tbody>
            { legislatorList }
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
```

The click event re-assigns this.state.legislators to the output of the a sort function.

```
handleChange( value ) {
    this.setState( { legislators: this.sort_by( value) })
  }
```

But the table remains the same even though the updated state of state.legislators is correctly sorted.

I think my problem is that the child Legislator components of Legislators is not updating its state. So my question is how do you update the state of child components?

Before Any Sorting:
[image]

After Sorting by First Name:
[image]

Other Functions of Legislators:

```
sort_by(sort_by) {
  const sorted = this.state.legislators.sort(function(a, b) {
    a_val = a[sort_by]
    b_val = b[sort_by]
    if (a_val < b_val) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a_val > b_val) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
  return sorted
}

renderLegislator(legislator) {
  return <Legislator legislator={ legislator}/>
}

populateList() {
  return this.state.legislators.map((legislator) =>
    this.renderLegislator(legislator)
  )}
}
```

Here is the Legislator component:

```
class Legislator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      legislator: props.legislator,
      fields: ["first_name", "last_name", "state", "party"]
    }
  }

  render() {
    const legislatorRow = this.state.fields.map((field) =>
        <LegislatorField value={ this.state.legislator[field] } />
    )
    return (
      <tr key={this.state.legislator.id}>
        { legislatorRow }      
      </tr>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please paste the content of `populateList()` and `sort_by()` as well

Comment: Try to put `console.log` in the callback function of the second parameter of `setState` or in `componentDidUpdate` function to check out if the component is really updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `state.legislator` in your child component is not being updated because the code:

```
this.state = {
  legislator: props.legislator,
  fields: ["first_name", "last_name", "state", "party"]
}
```

only runs once as the constructor only runs once, too. And the `state.legislator` in child component won't automatically update unless you do `this.setState()` explicitly inside the child component.

However, there is no need to do in such a way you are doing. Maintaining own state for `props` in the child component is absolutely redundant.

You can directly use `this.props` inside `render` method in child component, and when the `state` changes in the parent component, the child will re-render with new props.

```
 class Legislator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      fields: ["first_name", "last_name", "state", "party"]
    }
  }

  render() {
    const legislatorRow = this.state.fields.map((field) =>
        <LegislatorField value={ this.props.legislator[field] } />
    )
    return (
      <tr key={this.state.legislator.id}>
        { legislatorRow }      
      </tr>
    );
  }
}
```

As a bonus, if your `this.state.fields` is always constant -- you don't intend to update it later, you do not have to have it as a state either. You can simply make it a class instance field as `this.fields = ["first_name", "last_name", "state", "party"]`

Comment: thanks! yeah, changing this.state to this.props in the render functions fixed it

Comment: You should also consider Marco's answer about not mutating the state directly.

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is that `Array.prototype.sort` mutates the array and returns it, instead of returning a new array sorted.

```
 a = [4,1,2,3];
 b = a.sort();
 a === b // true , they are the same object
```

So when you "change the state" in `handleChange` you're actually mutating the state assigning the same object reference, making it difficult to React to tell that you've made any changes at all.

The easy way out would be to use [Immutable](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) to store the collection of legislators. Using `Immutable.List.sort` you will have a new array with the new value, instead of the old array mutated.

Other way out would be to define your component more clearly by having a `sortBy` property on the state that contains the key to sort the list by, and updating that instead of the whole collection.

**`constructor`**

```
this.state = {
  legislator: props.legislator,
  fields: ["first_name", "last_name", "state", "party"],
  sortBy: 'first_name'
}
```

**`handleChange`**

```
handleChange( value ) {
  this.setState( { sortBy: value })
}
```

**`populateList`**

```
populateList() {
  return this.state.legislators.map((legislator) =>
    this.renderLegislator(legislator)
  ).sort(function(a, b) {
     a_val = a[this.state.sortBy]
     b_val = b[this.state.sortBy]
     if (a_val < b_val) {
       return -1;
     }
     if (a_val > b_val) {
       return 1;
     }
     return 0;
   });
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning [Immutable](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/). Awesome library especially with React, but should be used with js application :D

Comment: so when setting the state I would use Immutable like this:
this.state = {
      legislators: Immutable.List(props.legislators)
    }
And then in handleChange:
const sorted = this.state.legislators.sort(function(a, b) {...}