# React child component do not re-render on it state change

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx, axios, rerender

I have a Tasks component which returns other components. However, when I change the state of one of the child's components from Tasks component, it does NOT re-render.

Im passing the 'newTaskAdded' state from the parent to the child as props and assign it to the child state in order to re-render the child component, but it still not happening.

My goal is: 
When a user adds a task, I want it to to be shown immediately on screen, in the mean the user has to refresh to page to see the new task.

Tasks.jsx:

```
import React , { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Name from './Name.jsx'
import ShowTasks from './ShowTasks.jsx'

class Tasks extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state={
      task: '',
      newTaskAdded:false,
      newTask:[],
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.addTask = this.addTask.bind(this)
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({task: event.target.value})
  }
  addTask() {
    axios.post('/api/addtask',{
      name:this.props.name,
      task:this.state.task
    })
    .then((res) => {
      if(res.status=='200'){
        this.setState ({task:''})
        this.setState ({newTaskAdded:true})
        this.setState ({newTask: res.data.message[res.data.message.length-1] })
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if(err) throw err
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Name name={this.props.name} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input value={this.state.task} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" name="task" />
          <button type="button" onClick={this.addTask}>Add Task</button>
        </div>
        <ShowTasks name={this.props.name} updated={this.state.newTaskAdded} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Tasks
```

ShowTasks.jsx

```
import React , { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Completed from './Completed.jsx'
import NotCompleted from './NotCompleted.jsx'

class ShowTasks extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      tasks:[],
      updated:this.props.updated
    }
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    axios.post('/api/loadtasks', {
      name: this.props.name
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log('res', res);
      this.setState ({tasks:res.data.tasks})
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      throw err
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='pointer'>
        {this.state.tasks.map((task) => {
          if(task.completed) {
            return <Completed key={task._id} {...task} />
          }
          else {
            return <NotCompleted key={task._id} {...task} />
          }
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ShowTasks
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `then` part is being executed? Do you get the console logs?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41971336/3734057

Comment: Thanks for the response @Chris. it does work

Answer (score 2):

So the problem is in your child function where you are setting props to state,

You are setting props to state in the constructor and the contructor is not called everytime the props change but only the first time when the component renders and hence the state doesn't get updated with the correct values.

You should be setting the props in the componentWillReceiveProps function that is called on every render of the parent component

```
class ShowTasks extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      tasks:[],
      updated:this.props.updated
    }
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      this.setState({updated: nextProps.updated});
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    axios.post('/api/loadtasks', {
      name: this.props.name
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log('res', res);
      this.setState ({tasks:res.data.tasks})
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      throw err
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='pointer'>
        {this.state.tasks.map((task) => {
          if(task.completed) {
            return <Completed key={task._id} {...task} />
          }
          else {
            return <NotCompleted key={task._id} {...task} />
          }
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ShowTasks
```

Read more about the lifecycle functions and when to use them **[here:](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html)**

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. but it still not working.
the componentWillMount function is not being accessed.

Comment: What do you mean by componentWillMount is not being accessed

Answer (score 0):

OK! solved:

Tasks.jsx:

```
import React , { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Name from './Name.jsx'
import ShowTasks from './ShowTasks.jsx'

class Tasks extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state={
      user:this.props.user,
      task:'',
      newTask:[],
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.addTask = this.addTask.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({task: event.target.value})
  }

  addTask() {
    axios.post('/api/addtask',{
      name:this.state.user.name,
      task:this.state.task
    })
    .then((res) => {
      if(res.status=='200'){
        this.setState ({user:this.state.user})
        this.setState ({newTask: res.data.message[res.data.message.length-1] })
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if(err) throw err
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Name name={this.props.user.name} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input value={this.state.task} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" name="task" />
          <button type="button" onClick={this.addTask}>Add Task</button>
        </div>
        <ShowTasks user={this.state.user}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Tasks
```

ShowTasks.jsx:

```
import React , { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Completed from './Completed.jsx'
import NotCompleted from './NotCompleted.jsx'

class ShowTasks extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      user: this.props.user,
      tasks:[],
    }
    this.loadTasks=this.loadTasks.bind(this)
  }

  loadTasks() {
    axios.post('/api/loadtasks', {
      name: this.state.user.name
    })
    .then((res) => {
      this.setState ({tasks:res.data.tasks})
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      throw err
    })
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.loadTasks()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='pointer'>
        {this.state.tasks.map((task) => {
          if(task.completed) {
            return <Completed key={task._id} {...task} />
          }
          else {
            return <NotCompleted key={task._id} {...task} />
          }
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ShowTasks
```